# Finding path where add-ins are installed for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, installation, vb.net, add-in

I see that my add-ins are installed to 
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.0\AssemblyCache{6C90269B-D233-4122-3747-C2AE1131E22C}

Is it possible to find that file path from within the Add-in itself?  e.g., someone would click a button and it would tell them the path where the add-in is located.

I want to use this location to store user-defined configuration info.

Comment: won't let me post my own answer yet, so here it is:     This returns full path to the .dll

 Public Function FindMe() As String

        FindMe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location '
        MsgBox(FindMe)
        return FindMe

    End Function

Comment: You might consider creating a well-known folder under %APPDATA% to store user configuration data rather than in the AssemblyCache folder as this is subject to deletion by the add-in framework and as you have seen requires reflection to determine.

Comment: @user4979: you might want to check out this question if you are looking at adding user scoped settings: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/esri-arcmap-add-in-with-app-settings-not-recognizing-app-config-changes

Comment: @blah238 user4979 has not been seen here for over 3 years, and I do not have the knowledge to translate their (and/or your) comment into an answer.  Could you perhaps do so sometime?

Comment: @PolyGeo It was not an answer, just a suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the **C#** code to get the addin assembly folder:

```
public static string AssemblyDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
                UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
                string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
                return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            }
        }
```

and **VB.NET**:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property AssemblyDirectory() As String
    Get
        Dim codeBase As String = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase
        Dim uri__1 As New UriBuilder(codeBase)
        Dim path__2 As String = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri__1.Path)
        Return Path.GetDirectoryName(path__2)
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python, you can find the folder location by doing the following

```
import os
print os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Comment: Python add-ins did not appear until ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop and this is a 10.0 question so the type of add-ins involved are described at http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000000w2000000