# Is it possible to store a default symbology layer in an arcpy add-in?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, layers, python-addin

Since arcpy is limited in how symbology can be manipulated, I was curious to know if a symbology layer can be stored in an arcpy add-in.  Does anyone know if it is possible to store a .lyr file, or anything else for that matter, in a .esriaddin so that it can be used once the addin is installed?

Comment: See Answer and Comments at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64966/should-python-add-in-installed-in-map-which-is-packaged-be-part-of-mpk - it should be possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any file included in the `Install\` directory of your add-in project will be carried along in the Python add-in when you run `makeaddin.py`. You can include layer files or anything else really. You'll find the absolute path to them on disk via

```
path_to_layer = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'mylayer.lyr')
```

in your `whatever_addin.py` to find them when they're installed. Once you've got that, you can use [`arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000003p000000) or [`arcpy.management.ApplySymbologyFromLayer`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000006n000000) as usual.