# Using EntityFramework in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I want to use an ORM  to retrieve some data from The SQLServer such as  user permissions. I am using ArcObjects SDK 10.4 .

Although I have added  the EntityFramework 6.0 and  my tables  to  a model , but in runtime it says  there is not any ConnectionString Name  for my Context.

Is is possible to  use EF  in ArcObjects?

Comment: as long as your data isn't versioned--it should be doable.  It sounds like EF can't find the connection string--you should probably read through this Q&A: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/arcmap-add-in-with-app-settings-not-recognizing-app-config-changes  .

Comment: I finally  was forced  to  use The DataSet(.ext) insted of  EF..It works for me.